# How to convert a pytorch model to ONNX

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, stm32, onnx

I want to convert a pytorch model to ONNX because I need to port the model on an embedded platform using STM32CubeIDE.

Python code:

```py
cp = torch.load('bestmodelw.pth')
mymodel.load_state_dict(cp['state_dict'])
mymodel.eval()

example = torch.randn(1, 4, 128)
torch.onnx.export(mymodel,
                  example,
                  onnxpath,
                  input_names = ['input'],
                  output_names = ['output'],
                  export_params = True,
                  verbose = True,
                  opset_version = 15)
```

I obtain a *.onnx* file but if I open the model with *Netron*, I can see that each convolutional layer has 2 inputs [(show image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hftdu.png). STM32CubeIDE doesn't support convolutional layers with 2 inputs so I can't use this model.
Could anyone please help me?

STM32CubeIDE also supports `.h5` files so I tried to convert the `.onnx` to a keras model (`.h5`) but this error message occurs:

```
KeyError: 'ReduceMin'
```